# In PyTorch's "MaxPool2D", is padding added depending on "ceil_mode"?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, padding, max-pooling

In `MaxPool2D` the padding is by default set to 0 and the `ceil_mode` is also set to `False`. Now, if I have an input of size `7x7` with `kernel=2,stride=2` the output shape becomes `3x3`, but when I use `ceil_mode=True`, it becomes `4x4`, which makes sense because (if the following formula is correct), for `7x7` with `output_shape` would be `3.5x3.5` and depending on the `ceil_mode` it would be either `3x3` or `4x4`.

[image]

Now, my question is, if the `ceil_mode=True`, does it change the default `padding`?

If it does, then how is it adding the padding i.e. is it adding the padding on left first or right, up first or down?

Answer (score 7):

Ceil_mode=True changes the padding.

> In the case of ceil mode, additional columns and rows are added at the right as well as at the down. (Not top and not left). It does not need to be one extra column. It depends on the stride value as well. I just wrote small code snippet where you can check how the populated values are pooled in either modes.

Before I found the [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/ceil-mode-in-pooling/54646/2) referenced above, I experimented the same way with your problem, it also seems as though the zero-padding is not used during the pooling operation, as in my following example the zeros would have been the maximum elements to be taken, but this does not seem to be the case.

```
    test_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(2,7,7).random_(-10,-5)
    print(test_tensor)
    max_pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, ceil_mode=True)
    print(max_pool(test_tensor))
    max_pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, ceil_mode=False)
    print(max_pool(test_tensor))
```

Random sample tensor:

```
    tensor([[[ -6.,  -9.,  -7., -10.,  -6.,  -8.,  -6.],
             [-10., -10., -10.,  -6., -10.,  -9.,  -6.],
             [-10.,  -7.,  -7.,  -8., -10., -10.,  -9.],
             [ -8., -10., -10.,  -9.,  -9., -10.,  -9.],
             [ -8.,  -6.,  -8.,  -6.,  -7.,  -7.,  -9.],
             [-10.,  -8.,  -7., -10.,  -9.,  -6.,  -8.],
             [-10.,  -6.,  -9., -10.,  -9.,  -9., -10.]],

            [[-10.,  -8.,  -6., -10.,  -9.,  -6.,  -7.],
             [ -7.,  -7., -10., -10.,  -6.,  -9.,  -7.],
             [ -6., -10.,  -7.,  -8.,  -8., -10.,  -9.],
             [ -8.,  -8.,  -6.,  -7.,  -6.,  -8.,  -6.],
             [ -9.,  -8.,  -7., -10.,  -8.,  -8.,  -7.],
             [-10., -10.,  -6.,  -9.,  -8.,  -8.,  -8.],
             [-10.,  -6.,  -9.,  -9.,  -7.,  -9., -10.]]])
```

ceil_mode=True

```
    tensor([[[ -6.,  -6.,  -6.,  -6.],
             [ -7.,  -7.,  -9.,  -9.],
             [ -6.,  -6.,  -6.,  -8.],
             [ -6.,  -9.,  -9., -10.]],

            [[ -7.,  -6.,  -6.,  -7.],
             [ -6.,  -6.,  -6.,  -6.],
             [ -8.,  -6.,  -8.,  -7.],
             [ -6.,  -9.,  -7., -10.]]])
```

ceil_mode=False

```
    tensor([[[-6., -6., -6.],
             [-7., -7., -9.],
             [-6., -6., -6.]],

            [[-7., -6., -6.],
             [-6., -6., -6.],
             [-8., -6., -8.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

When `ceiling_mode = True`, Pytorch uses `ceil` instead of `floor` to compute the output shape. This is equivalent to padding one column to the right and/or one row at the bottom.

An example below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
x = torch.rand(1, 1, 4, 3)
p = nn.MaxPool2d(2, ceil_mode=True)

print(x)
> tensor([[[[8.7051e-01, 7.7555e-01, 9.8731e-01],
            [9.9150e-01, 6.5547e-04, 5.2213e-01],
            [9.9981e-01, 9.8849e-01, 9.9986e-01],
            [8.4636e-01, 7.9657e-01, 6.3381e-01]]]])
print(p(x))
> tensor([[[[0.9915, 0.9873],
            [0.9998, 0.9999]]]])
```

- added one column to the right (with values `-$\infty$`)